# How does using ellipses for SFINAE work?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, sfinae

When using SFINAE to select constructor overloads in the past, I have typically used the following:

```
template <typename T>
class Class {
public:
    template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<U>::value, int>::type=0>
    Class() {
        std::cout << "void" << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<U>::value, int>::type=0>
    Class() {
        std::cout << "not void" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

However, I just came across this alternative:

```
template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<U>::value>::type...>
Class() {
    std::cout << "void" << std::endl;
}
```

Considering that the following is illegal ...

```
template <typename U = T, void...> // ERROR!
Class() { }
```

... how does the alternative above using ellipses rather than a non-type template argument work?

---

Full code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64a1aaf13ce6099b

Comment: @peppe But `template<typename U = T, void>` is illegal as well. Wouldn't that need to use `void` as a default argument to a type parameter? As in, `template <typename U = T, typename V = std::enable_if<...>::type>`?

Comment: @peppe As a template *type* parameter, not as a template non-type parameter.

Comment: @Barry: IOW `template<typename std::enable_if<condition>::type>` is illegal because it would deduce `void` if the `condition` is true, as that's a non-type parameter, while `template<typename std::enable_if<condition, int>::type>` is legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer was wrong. Sorry. I'm just going to fix it.

---

This declaration:

```
template <typename U = T, void...>
Class() { }
```

violates [temp.res]/8:

> The program is
>   ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if [...] every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack

It's no diagnostic required, but the compiler chooses to issue one anyway. Either way, the code is ill-formed.

On the other hand

```
template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<U>::value>...>
Class() { }
```

doesn't violate this requirement. We have an empty pack, so we don't run afoul of the fact that you can't use `void` as a non-type template parameter. Additionally, a hypothetical specialization of `enable_if` could provide a type that isn't `void` there so it's not ill-formed due to the above limitation.

Comment: I've tested the code with `enable_if_t<..., int>` and clang also does not compile it accusing both `Class2<void>` and `Class2<int>` to be ambiguous. Not sure if clang is right though...

Comment: @W.F. That's a known bug, fixed on trunk IIRC.

Comment: @zennehoy I know you accepted already my answer, but I'm not pretty sure it was wrong so I changed it. Sorry.

Comment: @Barry No worries! I actually like this syntax better than the `int=0` variant, so I'm glad it is well-formed. Using `std::enable_if_t` makes it even nicer.

Comment: I'm not convinced. `std::enable_if` cannot be specialized, on pain of UB, so a hypothetical sufficiently smart compiler can still diagnose this (on the "every valid specialization requires an empty pack" ground) even assuming that empty `void` packs are legal (which I'm also somewhat dubious about).