# Is SFINAE on unspecializable std templates ill-formed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is the following legal?

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<false, T> foo() {}
```

Usually, we have [[temp.res]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.res#general-6.1)

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> 1. no valid specialization can be generated for a template [...] and the template is not instantiated [...]

Clearly, no valid specialization can be generated for `foo`... unless you consider that `std::enable_if` could possibly be specialized such that `type` is present as `void` regardless of the first `bool` argument.

```cpp
struct S {};
template<bool B>
struct std::enable_if<B, S> : std::type_identity<void> {};
```

Except... you can't specialize `std::enable_if` by [[meta.rqmts]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/meta#rqmts-4)

> Unless otherwise specified, the behavior of a program that adds specializations for any of the templates specified in [meta] is undefined.

To summarize, if you wrote a [custom `enable_if`](https://godbolt.org/z/co9caz) that mimics `std::enable_if`, the first snippet is legal. The question is whether the prohibition on specializing `std::enable_if` makes it illegal?

<sub>This post is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65475745/4832499) answer. The current form is adapted from an implementation of an independent library.</sub>

Comment: I don't see how a user defined `enable_if` will help.  `enable_if` depends on a value, not a type so you can only specialize it for `true` and `false`.

Comment: @NathanOliver The second parameter of a custom `enable_if` is still a template parameter that can be specialized on, as in the second snippet. It's just that we usually don't think of it that way.

Comment: Aha.  I suppose you could do that, but then you're not really doing what you say your doing.  `enable_if<false, T>` should evaluate to nothing so it works correctly.  Sounds like what you really need is `std::conditionial`, not `std::enable_if`.

Comment: @NathanOliver This is language-lawyering, with the most convoluted possible combination of rules :P It did happen in practice, and I really meant `std::enable_if` and not `std::conditional`. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Mn3hdx) as an example. There are even more bizarre rules surrounding that though.

Comment: If you're not allowed to do a thing, then doing the thing you're not allowed to do is illegal. From that point forward, it no longer matters what *else* you may have done. I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: @NicolBolas The question is about how exactly these rules work together, which may eventually lead to confusing behaviour. IMO neither is an ideal state of affairs. One is the (arguably?) intended behaviour, the other is surprising, unless laid out bare like this.

Comment: As specified in [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/meta#trans.other), `std::enable_if` cannot have dummy specialization from compiler to have an (unreachable) valid type.

Comment: @PasserBy: There is no "work together". If you rob a bank, whether you stole the getaway car isn't important for determining if your actions were criminal. It may add to your slate of charges, but that's irrelevant to the question of whether you're in jail.

Comment: Technically, dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834149/how-does-using-ellipses-for-sfinae-work

Comment: @LanguageLawyer It didn't explicitly mention [meta.rqmts]/4, otherwise it's indeed technically a dupe, with an opposite answer to this one (yikes).

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't think it's as clear cut as your analogy. Even if it is, surprising behaviour is worth questioning. To arrive at the conclusion you had to 1. realize there's [temp.res] 2. realize specializations bails you out 3. realize there's [meta.rqmts]. Every time you dig deeper, the validity of the program flips, and it's all NDR. People also generally don't expect a standard library template that's obviously user-implementable to behave differently to the extent it causes UB.

Comment: @PasserBy: There is only "deeper" if you didn't know about [meta.rqmts] to begin with. If you started from there, then it's clear that 1 and 2 are irrelevant because you already broke 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The question is whether the prohibition on specializing `std::enable_if` makes it illegal?

I would say that yes, it does. For starters, since such specialization would lead to undefined behavior, we can completely ignore the possibility of this ever happening. The contract is breached there, so discussing legality further is moot<sup>1</sup>.

Now, since we don't have to worry about specialization at all, we (as someone trying to determine the behavior of a program/implementation) can rely on to the described behavior in the standard. The description of `std::enable_if` specifies that it has no `::type` member when its bool argument is `false`. So we are guaranteed `std::enable_if<false, T>::type` is always ill-formed.

This leads to inevitably meeting the criteria in [temp.res]/8. And *now* the program is ill-formed NDR.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - That is after all the very purpose of the [meta] clause you quote. It's to allow assuming things about the behavior of standard library components. Specifically, so that an implementation may optimize around said expected behavior.</sub>